# node.js vs apache as http backend for multiplayer game

Tags: apache, node.js, websocket

I have a multiplayer game with a gateway and multiple servers based on node.js and websockets.

Now it of course has a client which all consists of static files (html, js, resources).

Currently I am serving them with node (express framework)

BUT

Is node the best solution for serving static files or should I switch to apache.

I don't have very much experience with high traffic. Maybe I should consider services like amazon s3 ?

---

plus here is a simplified version of how I serve files with express.js:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/' + req.params[0]);
});
```

Comment: If you're just serving static files, nginx is really the way to go (there's a few comparable ones, but Apache certainly isn't competitive with it!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) would definitely be a valid approach.  If you want to go with this approach, you'd be looking for something like [Amazon Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) - you probably wouldn't need the features of Amazon S3.  There's a list of different Content Delivery Networks in the wikipedia article I linked at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Express offers static-file-serving functionality. You could see how that's implemented, as it could already be an improvement on what you are doing (not reading the file every time, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but Express.js allows serving static files in a folder with a simple setting:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));`